# Chocolatey upgrade dbeaver to latest version

Tags: windows, dbeaver, chocolatey

I just installed chocolatey today and having problems upgrading dbeaver to the latest version via chocolatey cli.

First I ran `choco install dbeaver`, which installed version 23.3.2 of dbeaver. Then I tried to run `choco upgrade all` and `choco upgrade dbeaver`, but I alway get the following output:

> dbeaver v**23.3.2** is the latest version available based on your source(s).

I expected an upgrade to version **23.3.3**, since its the latest approved version according to [chocolatey version history](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/dbeaver#versionhistory).

Comment: On the chcolatey package page there is a panel stating: _"This package was approved by moderator TheCakeIsNaOH on 22 Jan 2024"_. Maybe you tried while it was still to be approved? Maybe it takes some time to be ready?

Comment: Right now if I run `choco search dbeaver` I get _"dbeaver 23.3.3 [Approved]"_

Comment: @Marco I tried upgrading several times, even while writing the post. Just now I tried running `choco search dbeaver` and also got "dbeaver 23.3.3 [Approved]". Now the upgrade is running correctly.
Did I misunderstand the upgrade steps, is a search necessary before upgrading?

Comment: Absolutely no, you can run upgrade immediately after install. I can only think that the upgrade package was not ready yet.